# Table in Derby with complex primary key

Tags: sql, derby

Is it possible to have a primary key composed of foreign keys `fk1`, `fk2`, `fk3`

Where:

- `fk1` should never be null
- `fk2` and `fk3` can be null

I have the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE role_mappings (
       ROLE_NAME            VARCHAR(64)       NOT NULL,
       NESTED_ROLE_NAME     VARCHAR(64)       DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIVILEGE_NAME       VARCHAR(64)       DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_NAME, NESTED_ROLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE_NAME),
       CONSTRAINT fk_access_roles_rm_1 FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_NAME) REFERENCES access_roles (ROLE_NAME),
       CONSTRAINT fk_access_privileges FOREIGN KEY (PRIVILEGE_NAME) REFERENCES access_privileges(PRIVILEGE_NAME),
       CONSTRAINT fk_access_roles_rm_2 FOREIGN KEY (NESTED_ROLE_NAME) REFERENCES access_roles(ROLE_NAME)
);
```

When I insert `NULL` into `NESTED_ROLE_NAME` or `PRIVILEGE_NAME`, I get:

```
Column 'NESTED_ROLE_NAME'  cannot accept a NULL value.
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key values must be unique. If you allow null values into these fields that makeup the primary key you will quickly run into trouble with non-uniqueness.  AVOId using null values would be my advice.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just adding a `MAPPING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (start with 1, increment by 1)` as a row key and making it the primary key instead.